# Как переместить поля в оформление заказа Woocommerce?

Tags: woocommerce

Как переместить выбор доставки в колонку "Оплата и доставка?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: менять файлы шаблонов в папке ваша-тема/woocommerce/checkout/

Comment: Поподробней бы, что именно менять?